# Lookup value from table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup, lookup

I have a table of item values with a category of color In row 1 with color codes in the column that correspond to that category. Ex column A is red and in cell A20 is color code 221. But there a some color codes where 221 is red but 222(a slightly more darker tone) is under the brown column even though I would classify it as a red.

The table I have now has color categories in A1:L1 color codes from A2:L67 but most of those cells are blank. Column G has 66 values while Column F only has 23. If that’s going to play a factor.

For ease of sorting these items i would like to use lookup or match to enter in a color code and it give what color category it belongs too. So if I enter color code 321 it would give Brown as the color category. And id rather not just do control F and typing the code to see what column it’s in

| Red | Brown |
| --- | --- |
| 221 | 321 |
| 56 | 788 |
| 334 | 222 |
|  | 444 |
|  | 567 |

| Code | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 321 | Brown |

I have watched a few videos on v v lookup and I have tried transposing the table to correspond to the video. But since my idea calls for a variable column index number  based on what cell value I give it doesn’t work as I intend. So I’m stuck with that aspect.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `FILTER()` with `MMULT()` function.

```
=FILTER(A1:B1,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(A2:B6),,0),--(A2:B6=A13)))
```

Another approach could be using `BYCOL()` function.

```
=FILTER(A1:B1,BYCOL(A2:B6,LAMBDA(col,SUM(--(col=A13)))))
```

Extend range in your actual case.

[image]

Comment: @RBSalzman18 If it helps then please accept the answer (tick mark it).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data it's like this:

[image]

The formula to locate the color is:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1;1;SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$C$6=A11)*COLUMN($A$1:$C$1)))
```

This will work only if each id in colors dataset **is unique**.